# Odd behavior with Moose, Try::Tiny, and TryCatch

Tags: perl, moose

I've just started working with Moose and have run into an odd problem that I cannot figure out. The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;

{
    package Foo;
    use Moose;
    has x => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Int' );
}

my $f; 
try {
    $f = Foo->new(x => 'x');
} catch {
    die "oops\n";
}
print $f->x . "\n";
```

produces:

```
Can't call method "x" on an undefined value at m2.pl line 19.
```

However, if I replace `Try::Tiny` with `TryCatch`, it acts as I would assume it should:

```
oops
```

Even if `x` is the correct value, say `5`, `Try::Tiny` still produces the `undefined value` error.

As all of the Moose documentation I have been reading uses `Try::Tiny`, I'm very confused on why this code isn't working. Am I doing something completely wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Try::Tiny` requires a semicolon at the end of a try/catch stanza:

```
try {
    $f = Foo->new(x => 'x');
} catch {
    die "oops\n";
};
```

This is due to the implementation of `Try::Tiny` -- `try` and `catch` are both just functions.

Comment: Gah, an embarrassing overlook. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try { ... } catch { ... } isn't a builtin (since it is provided by a module). In perl 5 this means that you have to end it with a semicolon like so:

```
try {
    $f = Foo->new(x => 'x');
} catch {
    die "oops\n";
};
print $f->x . "\n";
```

I can't answer how TryCatch manages to handle the missing semicolon - but it is possible using various black magic :)

Comment: TryCatch uses Devel::Declare to modify the parser. It effectively creates new parsing rules for the try/catch block rather than depending on creative use of prototypes and anonymous subs.

Comment: Devel::Declare has some controversy associated with it related to the "too much magic" problem:  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=832796